# Is there an equivalent of BufferedReader.readLine() that lets me pick what my end of line characters are?

Tags: java, io, newline, line-endings

The Javadoc for [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) says:

> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'),
>   a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

I need slightly better control than this (e.g. I would like to be able to specify that an end of line is "\r\n", so that an "\n" by itself does not terminate the line).

Is there any JDK or library function which does this?

Comment: I suspect the behaviour is to allow text files to behave the same irrespective of platform, so it hides that detail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:

```
String line = Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\r\n").next();
```

Comment: Bitter experience suggests it's worth mentioning that Scanner uses an Iterator-style API (hasNext/next), and throws NoSuchElementException rather than returning null when there's no more input

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the use case for which you need the BufferedReader, you can maybe change over to using the Scanner class, which is able to read text from different sources (files, streams), and has a direct method th specify the delimiting pattern. 
See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard API that would acomplish this.

It's possible to simple read in the WHOLE file into a String and then split it at your desired ending character.

```
for(String line: testFile.split("\r\n")){
...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately our files are generally going to be far too large for this to work.