# bufferedreader is one line behind on real device

Tags: android, sockets, bufferedreader

I got an socket client that i use to receive data from a server. In the emulator all works well, however on my android the messages are always lagging one behind on thus my GUI isn't updated with the new data.

The code involved (the client runs in a Asynctask)

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) { //This runs on a different thread
    try {
        Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Creating socket");
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.x.xxx", 9090);
        nsocket = new Socket();
        nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 5000); //10 second connection timeout
        if (nsocket.isConnected()) { 

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nsocket.getInputStream()));
            wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(nsocket.getOutputStream()));
            Log.i("KMC.AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Socket created, streams assigned");
            sockState = true;

            String inputLine = "";
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result = inputLine.replace("\\","");
                Log.d("KMC", "Got some data: " + result);
                this.publishProgress(1);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("KMC.AsyncTask", "doInBackground: IOException");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("KMC.AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Exception");
    } finally {
        try {
            nis.close();
            wr.close();
            nsocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("KMC.AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Finished");
    }
    return true;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result.substring(1, result.length()-1));
            if(jObject.getString("type").equals("event")){
                EventHandler.newEvent(jObject.getString("name"), jObject.getJSONArray("data"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I've tried to find a solution on google, but i can't find anything on this.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706105/is-there-an-equivalent-of-bufferedreader-readline-that-lets-me-pick-what-my-en

Comment: I append "\r\n" to every transmission. Besides that: it works well on the emulator, but not on my phone (on ICS as well as ginger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

I changed the server to send a double "\r\n", that solved it somehow.